# Showing last loaded views - like facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, iphone

In many iOS apps like facebbok/instagram - when we freshly open the app(after forceful quit) they show last loaded views in every pages even there is no internet.
How is it possible ?
Saving this much of images and other data to SQLite is not a practical solution I know ?
But I am not able to find an idea to do the same thing in my app.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I once created an app that had these capabilities. The app had a central point that can serve images. When asked for an image, it would first look in a cache directory. If the image was not present, it would serve out a temp image. And fetch the image.
My app showed tweets, the json of the twitter api was also cached but in a core data store.

So my advice is to create a couple of central points that fetch data from a url. Whenever possible they serve a cached version. The image cache has an upper limit of images to cache. The least used images are deleted when more than N images have to be stored.

The image cache works like this:

```
@interface WSImageCache : NSObject {
@private
    NSMutableArray * activeConnections;
    NSUInteger numberOfCachedImages;
    NSMutableArray * currentlyFetchingURLS;
}

+ (WSImageCache *)sharedImageCache;

- (void) cacheImagesFor:(Tweet *) tweet;
- (BOOL) imageIsCached:(NSString *) url;
- (BOOL) completeTweetIsCached:(Tweet*) tweet;

- (NSData *) fetchAvatarFor:(Tweet *) tweet;
- (NSArray*) fetchImagesIn:(Tweet *) tweet;

- (NSURL *) cachedImageForURLString: (NSString *) url;;
@end
```